# How to scrape HTML table in R using "rvest" for table with href in all columns?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I've tried a bunch of methods from similar questions on StackOverflow and so far have not been able to figure out why my code isn't scraping the full table using the rvest package.

I've tried to use the following code:

```
url <- "http://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/list_scorecard.asp?id=105252"
squash <- url %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="corebody"]/table[4]') %>%
  html_table()
```

But this just returns a table with the headers and not the actual content of the table.

I have also tried:

```
library("httr")
URL <- "http://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/list_scorecard.asp?id=105252"
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
GET(url = URL, user_agent("Mozilla/5.0"), write_disk(temp))

library("XML")
df <- readHTMLTable(temp)
df <- df[[4]]
```

But that too gives me a similar issue of an empty table. Is there something with the source code that I'm misinterpreting?

Comment: The HTML is malformed. It's missing `<tr>` tags to indicate rows.  Some web browsers will "fix" bad HTML. The code used by rvest doesn't correct for as many mistakes. Perhaps try something like RSelenium that will run to code through Chrome to clean it up. Or you'd have to write your own parser for this irregular data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this particular page uses invalid HTML code. It has nothing to do with the href in all columns. Each row of the table is missing an opening `<tr>` tag. This makes it very difficult for automated tools to parse. Here's a hack to extract the cells, manually organize them into 8 columns and then part the data into a data.frame

```
url <- "http://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/list_scorecard.asp?id=105252"
page <- url %>%
  read_html()
table <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="corebody"]/table[4]')
cells <- table %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath='.//td[not(@class="Line")]') %>% 
  html_text()
headers <- table %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath='.//th') %>% 
  html_text()

Ncol <- 8
rows <- sapply(split(cells, rep(1:(length(cells)/Ncol), each=Ncol)), paste, collapse="\t")
dd <- read.table(text=rows, header=F, sep="\t", col.names = headers)
head(dd)
#   X.  Bowdoin.College        Rating     Bates.College      Rating.1
# 1 1S    Squiers, Ian  Lapsed-member  Yousry, Mahmoud       5.724126
# 2 2S  Butler, Satya P Lapsed-member  Bonnell, Graham       5.845270
# 3 3S Cooley, George W Lapsed-member      Attia, Omar       5.725947
# 4 4S   Leech, Gannon       5.362050 Nambiar, Anirudh  Lapsed-member
# 5 5S Shonrock, Tyler       5.576421   Abbott, McLeod  Lapsed-member
# 6 6S    Khanna, Uday       5.208504  McComish, Benni       5.448778
#        Winner.s.Score        Winner Status
# 1      11-8,11-4,11-6 Bates College      C
# 2      11-4,11-5,11-5 Bates College      C
# 3     12-10,11-9,11-9 Bates College      C
# 4      11-7,11-6,11-4 Bates College      C
# 5 4-11,11-6,11-5,11-7 Bates College      C
# 6 11-3,11-8,5-11,11-9 Bates College      C
```

Comment: Oh wow, good to know that it's partly the website's fault. This solution works!